# Why I get {"empty":false} in Angular/Postman from RestController?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I have a method that should return a json to the front-end, but instead of the json I am getting {"empty":false} in the client, as you can see on the picture.

[image]

I am using spring-rest-controller in order to connect the front-end done with Angular and the back-end done with Java and Spring. The whole Java part works, and, debugging, in the return I have a filled JSON, but it doesn´t arrive to the client.

```
@PostMapping("/users/login")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.FOUND)
    public ResponseEntity<Object>  login(@RequestBody LoginEntity user) throws ParseException, JSONException {

     HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
     headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");

    UserEntity serviceResult = this.userService.login(user);

    JSONObject jsonToClient = new JSONObject();

    if (serviceResult.getUserName() == null && serviceResult.getEmail()==null) {
         jsonToClient.put("user name", null);
        jsonToClient.put("email", null);
    } else if(serviceResult.getUserName() != null && serviceResult.getEmail()!=null) {

        UserToken userToken = new UserToken();

        String token = getJWTToken(user.getEmail());

        userToken.setUserName(serviceResult.getUserName());
        userToken.setEmail(serviceResult.getUserName());
        userToken.setToken(token);

        jsonToClient.put("user name", userToken.getUserName());
        jsonToClient.put("email", userToken.getEmail());
        jsonToClient.put("token", userToken.getToken());


    }

    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(jsonToClient, HttpStatus.OK); 
    }
```

In the client console I am watching this: {"empty":false}

Comment: Does your controller have `@RestController` annotation?

Comment: Yes, I use this annotation

Comment: What does the datatype of the return object in angular look like? It wouldn't happen to be a single 'empty' field would it?

Comment: I have added a screen shot to show the response, cheers

Answer (score 0):

try switching to this signature :

```
public ResponseEntity<String>  login(@RequestBody LoginEntity user) throws ParseException, JSONException {
```

and change the return to this:

```
return new ResponseEntity<String>(jsonToClient.toString(), HttpStatus.OK);
```